# SSMS Addin - Add Keyboard Shortcut To CommandBarButton

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, ssms-addin

I'm writing SSMS addin. I added o CommandBarButton to Contextmenu

```
CommandBarButton exportOpenContent = (CommandBarButton)menuEditorBarCommandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Type.Missing, Parameter:"Global::CTRL+W, CTRL+W", Before:1, Temporary:true);
                exportOpenContent.Style = MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
                exportOpenContent.Caption = "Open Content";
                exportOpenContent.Tag = "Open Content";
                exportOpenContent.ShortcutText = "Ctrl+W, Ctrl+W";
                exportOpenContent.Click += OpenContent_Click;
```

I want to add this command to keyboard shortcut but I didn't fount anything do this. This command must work When I press CTRL+W,CTRL+W.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Old topic but for anyone still wondering,

Here is a link that might be useful if you want to bind a shortcut to a command (VSIX projects)

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualstudio/extensibility/binding-keyboard-shortcuts-to-menu-items

I know that's not the way to do for Addin projects, but Addin projects are now deprecated. We now use VSIX projects to extend Visual Studio or SSMS.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do it within the code of the add-in and I have found that, certainly when I created an add-in that there is not a lot of documentation out there to help.

I could only suggest creating your add-in as normal and then going through the 
"tools -> options -> keyboard" menu to link the add-in to a shortcut, perhaps that could work.